# How to maintain a top5 sql table using a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I know a view is much better suited for this purpose, but for some reason the hair-brained want me to use a trigger.

Basically I need to maintain a top 5 ratings table that updates every time a restaurant gets a new rating. I don't know how to do this since it seems like I actually need to read from the table I have the trigger on but Oracle will not let me.

```
drop view bestratings_rest;
create view bestratings_rest(rid, rat) as (select distinct rid, max(stars) from rating
group by rid);

drop table top5restaurants;
create table top5restaurants(rid int);

insert into top5restaurants(rid)
        select rid from top_rest
        where rownum <=5
        order by rat asc;



create or replace trigger top5_trigger
    after insert on rating
    for each row

    begin
    delete from top5restaurants;
    insert into top5restaurants
    select rid from top_rest
    where rownum <=5
    order by rat asc;
    end;
    /
--    
--
begin
update_reviews('Jade Court','Sarah M.', 4, '08/17/2017');
update_reviews('Shanghai Terrace','Cameron J.', 5, '08/17/2017');
update_reviews('Rangoli','Vivek T.',3,'09/17/2017');
update_reviews('Shanghai Inn','Audrey M.',2,'07/08/2017');
update_reviews('Cumin','Cameron J.', 2, '09/17/2017');
end;
/    
select * from top5restaurants;
```

Comment: inserts are (relatively) easy to deal with (since you can check if the inserted row belongs in the top 5 and make space in the top 5 for it if necessary). Updates and Deletes are more problematic (because then a new row may need to be found from the original table). Do you have to deal with those too?

Comment: Also, how should ties be dealt with? You have a tie, probably, in your sample data (I'm guessing the bare integer is the rating), but with only five possible rows; not clear what would happen with a tie for fifth place among more than five rows.

Comment: Ties can be dealt with arbitrarily. Yes the int is the rating. Yeah actually now that I am discussing it I realize that inserts are actually the only thing I have to worry about and I don't have to do updates or deletes. So i should be able to just use bestratings table to access ratings. I think

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT command for top5restaurants table is not correct. This must be -

```
insert into top5restaurants(rid)
select *
from (select rid
      from top_rest
      order by rat asc)
where rownum <=5;
```

Since Rownum will execute first than order if you go with previous approach.

As far as your trigger is concern, Using the same query as above, You may have below code -

```
create or replace trigger top5_trigger
after insert on rating
for each row
begin
    delete from top5restaurants;

    insert into top5restaurants
    select *
    from (select rid
          from top_rest
          order by rat asc)
    where rownum <=5;
end;
/
```

Comment: This doesn't work because top_rest (actually should be bestratings_rest) still accesses the ratings table, so oracle throws an error. Materializing the view creates a new error.